# 3 x string functions as a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using str replace to remove empty spaces in a comma delimitated string

```
str_replace(" ", "", $string);
```

I also wish to remove a possible trailing comma, which I can do with:

```
if (substr($string, -1, 1) == ',')
{
    substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```

I then also want to explode to an array:

```
explode(",", $string);
```

Would it be more efficient to use a regular expression for all of these, and if so, how?

Comment: `rtrim('abc,',',');` results in `abc` and `regex` has always little more overhead.

Comment: What must be the result for string like: `"abc, d e f , x   yz"`

Answer (score 3):

Here's all in one:

```
explode(',', trim(str_replace(' ', '', $string), ','));
```

To be precise - regexp equivalient is:

```
$ms = [];
preg_match_all('/\s*([^,]+)\s*,/', $string ,$ms);
echo'<pre>',print_r($ms),'</pre>';
```

Simple test:

```
$string = 'word, word2, word3, w4,  ';

$ts = microtime(true);
$r = explode(',', trim(str_replace(' ', '', $string), ','));
$te = microtime(true);
echo 'Time elapsed1: ' . ($te - $ts) . PHP_EOL;

$ts = microtime(true);
$ms = [];
preg_match_all('/\s*([^,]+)\s*,/', $string ,$ms);
$te = microtime(true);
echo 'Time elapsed2: ' . ($te - $ts) . PHP_EOL;
```

Shows that combination of functions is **faster**.

Comment: Thanks, would a regular expression be more efficient tho?

Comment: If you can do something without regular expression - __do__

Comment: This kind of test doesn't prove anything, see the difference when you reuse each one a second time: https://eval.in/725728 . Other thing, your pattern doesn't take in account lines that don't have a trailing comma. If we assume that items don't have spaces in the middle like `ab c` (that is the necessary condition to do it with a single regex), the pattern can be written like this: `/[^\s,]+/`.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be more efficient to use a regular expression for all of these, and if so, how?

For short strings and a small number of repetitions the difference is insignificant. The string functions you use, however, make the code more readable than the regular expressions.

Regarding the possible trailing comma I would use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) (or [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove both leading and trailing commas, if appropriate).

Combined they would be like this:

```
$string = 'abc, d e f, g h, ';
$pieces = explode(',', rtrim(str_replace(' ', '', $string), ','));
```

The output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "def"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "gh"
}
```

If you want to strip only the spaces that surround the commas and keep untouched the spaces that might appear inside the values then you need a different approach:

```
$string = 'abc, d e f, g h, ';
$pieces = array_map('trim', explode(',', rtrim($string, ', ')));
var_dump($pieces);
```

The output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "d e f"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "g h"
}
```